# How to cut a large sprite png into smaller UIImages?

Tags: iphone, uiimage

For example, the png file is 1200 (h) x 50 (w) pixels, how can I *cut* the png and loads in 6 `UIImage`s, each 200 (h) x 50 (w). Thanks!

EDIT - thanks to Michal's answer, the final code:

```
 CGImageRef imageToSplit = [UIImage imageNamed:@"huge.png"].CGImage;
 CGImageRef partOfImageAsCG = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageToSplit, CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50));

 UIImage *partOfImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:partOfImageAsCG]; 
 // ...

 CGImageRelease(partOfImageAsCG);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at CGImageCreateWithImageInRect function. It works with CGImage, but it's easy to convert between that one and UIImage.

Here's an example (typed from memory, might not compile):

```
CGImageRef imageToSplit = [UIImage imageNamed:@"huge.png"].CGImage;
CGImageRef partOfImageAsCG = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageToSplit, CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50));
CGRelease(imageToSplit);
UIImage *partOfImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:partOfImageAsCG];
CGImageRelease(partOfImageAsCG);
```

Comment: What you want is CGImageRelease() not CGRelease()

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I've fixed it and upped your comment.

Answer (score 2):

**A reusable method:**

```
-(UIImage*)ExtractImageOn:(CGPoint)pointExtractedImg ofSize:(CGSize)sizeExtractedImg FromSpriteSheet:(UIImage*)imgSpriteSheet
{
    UIImage *ExtractedImage;

    CGRect rectExtractedImage;

    rectExtractedImage=CGRectMake(pointExtractedImg.x,pointExtractedImg.y,sizeExtractedImg.width,sizeExtractedImg.height);

    CGImageRef imgRefSpriteSheet=imgSpriteSheet.CGImage;

    CGImageRef imgRefExtracted=CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imgRefSpriteSheet,rectExtractedImage);

    ExtractedImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRefExtracted];

    CGImageRelease(imgRefExtracted);

    //CGImageRelease(imgRefSpriteSheet); I have commented it because
    // we should not release the object that we don't own.
    // So why do we release imgRefExtracted alone? because it has 
    // name create in its method so the ownership comes to us so we
    // have to release it.

    return ExtractedImage;

}
```

*FYI:*

Even though it has been answered clearly I thought giving it as simple reusable 'Copy-Paste' code snippet would be a lots of help to programmers and I attribute the answer to [michal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215276/michal)