# How to reference specific part of the image?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I may not be using a proper term here, but ..

Suppose you have a deck of cards represented as **one big image**. From this image, i'd like to find a way to **reference each individual card separately**. How can this be done using `Objective-C?`

[image]

Comment: Are you seeking logical references to various cards, or you literally want one image turned into an array containing 9 images?

Comment: @isaac, Thank you for responding. I am looking for logical references only. Array of 12, in this case would be great

Comment: This answer might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766373/how-to-cut-a-large-sprite-png-into-smaller-uiimages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will provide access to part of the image, numbers will need to obviously be refined

```
CGImageRef bigImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bigImage.png"].CGImage;

CGImageRef partOfBigImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(bigImage, 
                 CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50));

UIImage *partOfImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:partOfImageAsCG];
```